# Hammer.js is blocking scroll events on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, touch, hammer.js

I've added Hammer.js events to an element on my site. They all fire correctly and everything is good, but an issue caught the eye of my designer. He noticed that when you try and scroll the page with your finger over the element, nothing happens. Unfortunately this is a game-breaker.

So my question is, how can you retain scrolling when using Hammer.js.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone out there looking for a solution, here's what I came up with.

```
this.$hammer = $('img').hammer();
this.$hammer.on('touchstart', fingerDown)
            .on('touchend', fingerUp)
            .on('pinch', setScale);

function fingerDown(e) {
  var fingersDown = e.originalEvent.touches.length;

  if (fingersDown > 1) {
    // Lock Scrolling over the zoom element by allowing Hammer.js to fire pinch events.
    toggleHammerScrolling(true);
  }
}

function fingerUp(e) {
  toggleHammerScrolling(false);
}

function toggleHammerScrolling(shouldScroll){
  //This is where your implementation may change. Just do .get('pinch').set... on your own hammer object.
  this.$hammer.data('hammer').get('pinch').set({
    enable: shouldScroll
  });
}

function setScale(){
  console.log('do pinching stuff here');
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the latest hammer.js 2.0.x.
It's not possible anymore to register an event handler for `touchstart` and `touchend`.

Comment: What works for me: I use hammer.js for `tap` and `press` events, while i rely on `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend`to manually handle the pinch gesture.